# Can I select the empty portion of an artboard that is not part of a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I have the following blue filled path that leaves a small portion of the artboard empty. I want to know if there's a way to select the inverse part of the artboard (the white part) and turn that into a path as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not directly.

But...

- Draw a rectangle filled with any color *other* than blue, to cover that bottom portion
- Move this new rectangle *behind* the blue
- Select both shapes
- Hit the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**

You'll end up with 2 shapes.

Comment: Easy & perfect!